# Deleted BOOTCAMP partition capacity went into Recovery HD

Tags: macos, recovery, partition, bootcamp

I am facing a weird problem and it is honestly driving me crazy!

I had a bootcamp partition (80 Go) with Windows 7 installed for a while. I then tried to remove this partition using Apple's Bootcamp Assistant but I encountered an error and was not able to do so. So I decided to boot in Recovery Mode, formatted the `BOOTCAMP` partition in the hope that I would later be able to merge it with my `Macintosh HD` one.

I succeeded in doing this, meaning that I then had `Macintosh HD` on one side, and an empty 80 Go `BOOTCAMP` partition on the other.

However, something went wrong in the process of merging them together and for some reason, I now have a capacity of 420 Go displayed on `Macintosh HD` (same as before), no `BOOTCAMP` partition displayed at all, and a `diskutil list` command showing me 80 Go for `Apple Recovery HD` (which correspond to my initial BOOTCAMP capacity):

```
➜  ~  diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            419.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             80.5 GB    disk0s3
```

When I launch the `First Aid` option in `Disk Utility` on `Apple SSD`, I get the following:

[image]

My only wish is to be able to recover my full 500 Go on `Macintosh HD` in order to later use bootcamp again and install Windows 10.

Looking forward to any kind of help,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had similar experience - but it was due to hard drive IO failures

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I've found a simple solution for my problem. For anyone experiencing the same issues, here's how I did it:

1. Format Recovery HD
2. Expand Macintosh HD through Disk Utility (now possible since Recovery HD is empty). Simply clicking on the empty part of the pie that represents the recovery partition and hitting "minus".
3. Recreate Recovery HD using [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/)

It worked flawlessly. I now have a fully-working Macintosh HD partition (500go), and a recovery partition that is only 650 Mb. I am able to boot on both Macintosh HD and Recovery HD, and the recovery tools report no errors.